# Pytorch resumes training after every training session

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I have a dataset which is partitioned into smaller datasets.

I want to train 3 models for each partition of the dataset, but I need all training sessions to start from the same initialised network parameters.

so it looks like this:

```
modelList = []
thisCNN = NNet()

for x in range(3):
    train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(Subset(train_set, indexes[x]), batch_size=32)
    bb = trainMyNet(thisCNN, train, test)
    modelList.append(list(bb.parameters()))

print modelList[0][1]
print modelList[1][1]
print modelList[2][1]
```

In the printing, I am getting the same exact parameters for every saved model which is strange, and also I noticed that after every iteration the model in fact resumes the training from the previous iteration as it results in lower loss per iteration.

What I am trying to achieve, is, per iteration to get a new model on the current subset `x` but the training should start with the same initial `thisCNN = NNet()` weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `bb = trainMyNet(thisCNN, train, test)` you are not taking a copy of `thisCNN`, but it is the same model you are updating in each iteration. To get your code working you should probably pass a copy of this model:

```
from copy import deepcopy    
modelList = []
thisCNN = NNet()

for x in range(3):
    train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(Subset(train_set, indexes[x]), batch_size=32)
    bb = trainMyNet(deepcopy(thisCNN), train, test)
    modelList.append(list(bb.parameters()))

print modelList[0][1]
print modelList[1][1]
print modelList[2][1]
```

This should initialize all models as `thisCNN` and make sure that they are different after training.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you pass `thisCNN` to `trainMyNet` you are passing the same network. So, the weights will be updated in the same place. You should declare `thisCNN` inside your for loop:

```
for x in range(3):
    thisCNN = NNet()
    train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(Subset(train_set, indexes[x]), batch_size=32)
    bb = trainMyNet(thisCNN, train, test)
    modelList.append(list(bb.parameters()))
```

Comment: Incorrect. I have tried this already, and, as expected, at each iteration, ` thisCNN = NNet()` get new initial weights.

Comment: Then, try `cnns = [NNet()] * 3` outside the for-loop. Inside it, you just call `cnns[x]` instead of `thisCNN`.

Comment: Also, please share your `trainMyNet`.